# How can I make an array of a block in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use to_sentence method on the block of code to return the names with , separated :

```
<% @products_in_category.each do |pic| %>
  <%= pic.name %>
<% end %>
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace each with map and it will return an array with the results of invoking the block on each element. So you can do

```
@products_in_category.map(&:name).to_sentence
```

Comment: Thnx, Can i make each name to be a link to the product in this way ? or its not possible in this method ?

Answer (score 2):

`<%= (@products_in_category.map {|x| x.name}).to_sentence %>`